# initWith vs arrayWith in objC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, collections, initialization

What are the pros and cons of creating an array (or any other collection using its respective factory method) with

```
[[NSArray alloc] init]
```

vs

```
[NSArray array]
```

in objective C? It seems like the latter factory method allows us to not worry about memory management, so I was curious if there's any point in ever using alloc + init, though I'm now more interested in all the differences between these two, and why one would choose one over the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory Usage on convenience method vs init method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289578/memory-usage-on-convenience-method-vs-init-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to ARC there was a critical difference.  The `alloc/init` case returned a *retained* object, while the `array` case returned an *autoreleased* object.

With ARC the difference is less important.  Probably the first case is a hair more efficient, but in most scenarios they are interchangeable.

Comment: I think you mean *autoreleased*, not *autoretained*.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, you have the ownership of array object & you have to release them.

```
NSMutableArray* p = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

[p release];

& last one you dont need to release as you don't have the ownership of array object.

```
NSMutableArray* p = [NSMutableArray]; //this is autoreleased
```

If you call release in this, then it will crash your application.